# ¿Comando exacto para ejecución de comando en Mikrotik a través de la API en PHP?

Tags: php

La idea es la siguiente, yo tengo una web para que los usuarios puedan reiniciar su conexión de Internet, pero quiero que el comando de reiniciar la interfaz del DHCP, que es "/ip dhcp-client release 0" le pueda ser enviado al Mikrotik mediante la API, la idea de la web es que cuando le den al botón reiniciar conexión, ejecute por detrás el fichero release.php el cual contiene este código para el reinicio de la misma pero no me funciona:

```
<?php
require('../routeros_api.class.php');
$API = new RouterosAPI();
$API->debug = true;
if ($API->connect('111.111.111.111', 'LOGIN', 'PASSWORD')) {
  $API->comm("/ip/dhcp-client/release/0"
  $API->disconnect();
}
?>
```

El problema es que estoy seguro que esta linea es la que no estoy poniendo bien:

```
   $API->comm("/ip/dhcp-client/release/0")
```

Si pudieran ayudarme, la idea es enviarle el comando al mikrotik para que remotamente y sin los usuarios acceder al equipo le del en Release a su conexión y dándole eso se les reinicia, saludos

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require('../routeros_api.class.php');

$API = new RouterosAPI();

$API->debug = true;

if ($API->connect('ip_del_MT', 'LOGIN', 'PASS')) {

   $API->write('/ip/dhcp-client/release/0');

   $API->disconnect();

}

?>
```

a mi me funciona asi tengo un MT con RouterOS v6.40.4

Answer (score 0):

```
$API->write('/ip/dhcp-client/release',false);
$API->write("=.id=0",true);
```

Esta es la solución que yo uso y me funciona. Debes cambiar donde dice 0 por el id de la interfaz que quieras hacer el release

Saludos